puppeteer config import order causes an error
i am using puppeteer in a nodejs module on a macos 14.5
$ jq -r '.type' package.json
module

$ jq -r '.devDependencies.puppeteer' package.json
22.11.0

i have a basic boilerplate as follows
$ cat puppeteer.config.cjs
// empty config

$ cat test.js
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import puppeteerConfig from "./puppeteer.config.cjs";
console.log("i am a puppet");

but i get an error upon execution
$ node test.js
node:internal/assert:14
    throw new ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION(message);
          ^

Error [ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION]: This is caused by either a bug in Node.js or incorrect usage of Node.js internals.
Please open an issue with this stack trace at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues

    at assert (node:internal/assert:14:11)
    at cjsLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:347:7)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:297:7)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24)
    at async asyncRunEntryPointWithESMLoader (node:internal/modules/run_main:123:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION'
}

Node.js v20.14.0

if i change the order of imports, the error is gone
$ cat test.js
import puppeteerConfig from "./puppeteer.config.cjs";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
console.log("i am a puppet");

$ node test.js
i am a puppet

i cannot debug further and don't understand why this is happening and would appreciate your help.

Both work fine for me on Node 20.11.1 and Ubuntu 22.04, Pupp 22.10.0. Generally, configs go top level rather than inside src, and I'm not sure why you need to import it into the script in any case. What are you trying to accomplish?

my code worked fine. then in each file, i sorted the imports and then the code got broken. digging made me found that the order of imports broke the code and i wonder why. when running on a linux platform all works for me, but fails on macos.

Tested on MacOS with multiple Node.js versions, can't reproduce.

@Mureinik which macos version? is it intel or apple silicon?

@Mr. Sonoma 14.5, m2 processor.

@Mr. you're showing us cat test.js, but then you run node src/test.js. Are they the same file?

@Mureinik you have sharp eyes :) it was a typo.

@Mureinik strange, it happens to me on macos with inter and apple chip.

i think it is related to import/require caching mechanism. when puppeteer is being required/imported, then it requires/imports the config file (automatically), which probably caching the config. later, when the config is being required/imported again, then things get messy...

the problem arises from the caching of modules in nodejs and in cosmiconfig, which is the module that puppeteer uses to read its configuration file
$ npm view puppeteer dependencies.cosmiconfig
9.0.0

the issue can be bypassed by using cosmiconfig to read the configuration file rather than importing it directly. something as follows worked for me.
import cosmiconfig from "cosmiconfig";
const explorerSync = cosmiconfig.cosmiconfigSync("puppeteer");
const { config } = explorerSync.load("./puppeteer.config.cjs");

